# Java EE strange entity behavior

Tags: java, windows, web, ejb

I'm experiencing a weird/odd behavior. I'm working on a project which is a web app using Java EE. It is deployed on GlassFish 3.1.1 using Eclipselink 2.3 persistence services. Everything is on Eclipse, Windows 7 professional 64 bit, JDK + JVM 64 bit.

I get a business object to work with. First I set the corresponding entity. Everything is fine up to the invocation of a method. If I debug inside this, the entity suddenly becomes null.

Before this invocation the entity is instantiated.

The code is this:

```
// get my entity  
tramiteProxy = ejbTramiteFactory.getEntity(tramite);  

// get corresponding business thru factory  
IRegistrableInLiquidador registrableInLiquidadorBusiness = (IRegistrableInLiquidador)     ejbTramiteFactory.getCBusiness(tramiteProxy);  


// invoke business  
// up to here everything is fine, you can inspect business variable and it shows correct, entity is instantiated as expected   

registrableInLiquidadorBusiness.registrarNovedadInIntegrador();
```

Now we go debugging inside the business object (`registrableInLiquidadorBusiness`):

```
// Here if one checks the entity it became null !!!  

public void registrarNovedadInIntegrador() throws CException {  
    try {  
        CIntegradorBusiness ejbIntegradorBusiness = CCTX  
            .getEJB(CIntegradorBusiness.class);  

        // Here's the problem: getEntity() returns null, the entity of this business object became *magically* null  

        ejbIntegradorBusiness.registrarNovedad(getEntity(),null);  

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        throw new CException(1, e);  
    }  
}
```

I must add that the object entity is a variable declared in the father of this business, from which it extends.

So I don't know what else to try. I looked at every single line of code that has to do with this for finding any mistake to no avail.

The next step would probably be downloading the Eclipselink source and debug it to see what's going on behind the scenes, though I don't even know if it has anything to do with this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the class perhaps an @Stateless bean and `registrarNovedadInIntegrador` a business method on that bean?

Comment: Yes it is a @Stateless anotated bean. After some research i must assume that being a Stateless bean, and therefore "keeping" it's state for 1 single request, if a want to set any property , like my entity , i should invoke a method on that class, setEntity(entity), after that call the state is lost so on the next call my entity is null (The EJB engine would provide me with another instance of the business EJB, not the one i was using before)

Comment: Exactly. Your analysis is correct; that specific aspect of stateless beans causes your entity to be null.